# How can I set "record" value using TRttiProperty.setValue()?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I set the value of the `TPoint` property using `TRttiProperty.setValue()`? Or any other property of type `record`?

Comment: Pass the instance in the first parameter and the record in the second parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `prop.setValue(self, point(11, 13));`? But this causes the error "Incompatible types (TValue and TPoint)" ...

Comment: Of course. You need to pass a TValue. Do some research on TValue. I know that I could tell you how to do it, but you can work this out for yourself with some research. You should want to learn how to be self sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Vertex: TPoint;
Val: TValue;

...

Vertex := Point(1, 22);
TValue.Make(@Vertex, TypeInfo(TPoint), Val);
Prop.SetValue(Self, Val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generic class method `TValue.From<>`

```
Vertex: TPoint;
Val: TValue;
...
Vertex := Point(1, 22);
Val := TValue.From<TPoint>(Vertex);
Prop.SetValue(Self, Val);
```